# Cursor does not appear in jTextfield and not able to type letters

Tags: java

I'm new to java i was working on simple java project. Here i have issue related to `jTextfield` it does not show cursor on click and i'm not able to type letter. also note i have enabled `editable` in `properties`.

Here is my image 
[image: output]

code

```
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
```

Frame Layout is Card Layout

Design Layout Type

```
if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean you can't gain focus on that window ?

Comment: Are you using a `null` layout? Is the field focusable and enabled?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer i can't gain focus i'm using card layout and i have enabled focusable